# Swift TableView Crash: "Missing cell for newly visible row"

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

Im experiencing a crash when adding new rows to a tableview. In short, the crash log says "Missing cell for newly visible row 3".

**Reproduction**
 1. Add N amount of objects to datasource
 2. Manually add the same amount
    of cells to tableview
 3. Reload and animate using beginUpdates - endUpdates

**Known Problem**
This crash has already been discussed at [question](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjG1JvS2pbRAhUGN1AKHZtqBKIQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F40358487%2Fcrash-with-missing-cell-for-newly-visible-row-when-updating-uitableview&usg=AFQjCNEd-J7qJSNlgT6CcBzRBUS9hMnjVQ&sig2=CYwzhTjKLZhjrzlk_ToPIg) and reported at [Apple](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjG1JvS2pbRAhUGN1AKHZtqBKIQFggxMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fforums.developer.apple.com%2Fthread%2F49676&usg=AFQjCNGfDNkgMAJ_zNKiuuJ9pXJxB-ALoA&sig2=cMh7Anoshaiz6q9jiFNH2Q). Their solution to this problem (not using estimated cell heights) does not work for me as i need 2 different heights for the cells.

My tableview is composed out of 2 different cell classes. Both have their own standard height, configured as such:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row % (straightsetLogs.count + 1) == 0 {
        return 44
    } else {
        return tableView.rowHeight
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // (exerciseSets.count / straightsetLogs.count) = amount of (super)sets
    // (straightsetLogs.count + 1) = amount of cells needed for 1 (super)set
    return (exerciseSets.count / straightsetLogs.count) * (straightsetLogs.count + 1)
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Headercell: 1 headercell for every (super)set
    if indexPath.row % (straightsetLogs.count + 1) == 0 {
        // Create header cells once for every set
        let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellID.setHeaderCell, for: indexPath) as! SetHeaderTableViewCell

        return configureHeaderCell(headerCell, forIndexPath: indexPath, totalCellsPerSet: straightsetLogs.count + 1)
    } else {
        // Create picker cells for rest of rows
        let pickerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellID.setPickerCell, for: indexPath) as! SetPickerTableViewCell

        // Configure according to set and movement
        return configurePickerCell(pickerCell, forIndexPath: indexPath, totalCellsPerSet: straightsetLogs.count + 1)
    }
}
```

In storyboard i've configured the tableview itself to have a row height of 260.0 and for the header cell i've checked the custom row height box and set it to 44.0.

**Current Status**
The code for determining the correct cells for the index paths works and the crash can be solved by removing the height for row at indexPath code. But then i end up with all cells being 260.0 height.

**Goal**
I need 44.0 height for header cells and 260.0 height for picker cells without experiencing this crash.

Comment: Write down your number of rows in section and cellforrow method as well

Comment: can you please try with  return 260 instead of         return tableView.rowHeight

Comment: That didn't work..

Comment: You refer to header cell and content cell, probably I missed something, but is not that easier to use different sections to get rid of this issue using iOS header instead? Btw if you put a little POC on github for sure it would be quicker to debug

Comment: @MatteoCrippa That is indeed a cleaner and saver solution for structuring the tableview. I was not aware of the fact that custom header views could be made. I'll rebuild it and see if the crash still occurs.

Comment: The problem was indeed the way i structured the model and tableview. It is solved now!

Comment: @FabijanBajo So to fix it, you followed the suggestion to split the table into sections, and use custom header views on each?

Comment: @mrgrieves That is indeed what i have done.