# Why estimatedSectionHeaderHeight leading application crash in one of my iPad?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need expandable listing in my application, So I have used sections list and main list and table rows and expanded list.
My expected section View's height is around 160 pixels, but it's dynamic based on content to display. So I write code as

```
self.tblBeerJournal.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tblBeerJournal.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 160
self.tblBeerJournal.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tblBeerJournal.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Which was working fine, But today I faced crash issue with error log as

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Missing cell for newly
>   visible row 0'

I follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/40899251/7575136
And noticed that if I comment my **estimatedSectionHeaderHeight** code that app is not crashing, But this will mess-up my all UI.

Anyone aware of this issue and its proper solution? please let me know if you can help me in this matter.

Thank You!

Comment: when will this crash happens ?

Comment: While I tap on section headers button(this will refresh rows for that section) and reload that section.

Comment: is this working fine without click on button ?

Comment: This issue is in some specific section and its coming every time for that section only rest all fine. FYI All section data is proper.

Comment: Yes, Also if I do not set estimated height than its working fine and section getting expanded as well.

Comment: can you share that code  ?

Comment: Refreshing only like:- self.tblBeerJournal.reloadSections(sections as IndexSet, with: .fade)

Comment: and app is getting crash in this line, FYI I wrote this line in DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(0.1) sec

Comment: try to change your line as self.tblBeerJournal.estimatedRowHeight = 100 .

Comment: Same issue for estimatedRowHeight = 100

Comment: see this may this helping you : http://stackoverflow.com/q/41360840/3901620

Comment: Actually, I have checked this code... Let me update by code as per that.

Comment: and did you insert or delete any rows on button action ?

Comment: No, only display rows by expanding/collapsing the section.

Comment: I do had delete style, Sorry i missed that

Comment: self.tblBeerJournal.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension  change this to 

self.tblBeerJournal.estimatedRowHeight = 100 or any value

Comment: and try to check in device instead of simulator

Comment: its working fine in my iPhone and simulator, but not in iPad air. ;(

Comment: Actually, I will need dynamic height for the rows as well, I tried static height for row fro testing purpose, but no success.

Comment: @AshwinIndianic First of all instead of using tableView property use tableview delegates for cell height. It directly effects on your performance. First try this and add piece of code work for more info.

Comment: I tried with both ways i.e with property and with the method, but no any success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for helping me in this matter,

What I found is, instead of **estimatedSectionHeaderHeight** If I go with below code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    var heightOfSection: CGFloat = 100
    heightOfSection = heightOfSection + dynamic_contents_height
    return heightOfSection
}
```

Will fix my problem, Also Its resolved some animation issue of expand and collapsed the section.

I'm posting my answer to let you know what I did now for this crash issue, Please correct me if you have a better solution.

Thanks :)